# File or array for temp data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get data from API and process it. I'm torn between using file or array. I tried both but I found out that apparently using array takes more time than file. Am I doing something wrong or is it true?

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely not true. A file would require I/O operations which are usually the slowest operations. Arrays, on the other hand, are stored in the memory which are really fast.

Choosing between an array and a file is easy. If you want to persist your data, use a file. If you don't want to persist your data and speed is all you are worried about, then go ahead with an array. I am assuming that you have narrowed down your choices to array and file after careful thinking, so I am not going to suggest alternatives.

Comment: My benchmarks show otherwise. And no, file is already there and I want to find a better way.

Comment: I mean it's implemented using file already. I want to change it.

Comment: Your benchmark is almost certainly flawed. Could you provide more details about how you are doing it?